# Getting to the entry point using radare2

Tags: radare2

How do I get to the entry point of a .exe file using radare2?
I tried using aa then pdf@sym.main, but a prompt showed saying "Cannot find function at 0x00000000"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The entrypoint can be found using the info command `i?` especially the entrypoint info command `ie`

```
[0x00404890]> ie
[Entrypoints]
vaddr=0x00404890 paddr=0x00004890 baddr=0x00400000 laddr=0x00000000

1 entrypoints
```

Alternatively you can use `rabin2 -e <file>`.